# PNG Images and InputStream in Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, inputstream

I need to decode an .png image to use it as a base to create some Rects and to use the image itself as a background for my application, but the try-catch keeps throwing me a Null Pointer Exception, this is the code:

```
    try {

        InputStream is = ParamsSingleton.assetManager.open("background.png");
        figure = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        height = figure.getHeight();
        width = figure.getWidth();

        src = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
        first = new Rect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Image decode fail!");

    }
```

I've tried some logs and the try-catch break right on the InputStream line and prints the 'Log.d' in catch block, I checked the file name and it is alright.

Comment: Your `open` method's signature seems to require a `String`, and yet you didn't encase `background.png` in double quotes. Also, it may be necessary to use the full path to the file.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but on the original code it was encased, I forgot to put ir back during the translation, thanks

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Comment: Have you tried using a fully qualified path to the file? You can try testing for the file's existence using [File#exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists())

Comment: 11-23 01:32:10.340: E/AndroidRuntime(28381): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity: ComponentInfo{MyPackageName.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.graphics.Rect.left' on a null object reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `getAssets.open` method inside `decodeStream` .

```
figure = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets.open("background.png"));
```